# Cannot read property 'responseXML' Google Map

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

*Using Google Chorme (lastest version) & Sublime Text.*

Hi i'm struck on my personnal project, i want to convert xml coordinates (of buses) into markers on google map, this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        initMap(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://applications002.brest-metropole.fr/WIPOD01/Transport/REST/getGeolocatedVehiclesPosition?format=xml&route_id=1&trip_headsign=Fort%20Montbarey", true);
xhttp.send();

function initMap(xml){
var xlat, xlon, inc, xmlDoc, GeoBus, marker;
xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; //line 48
xlat = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Lat');
xlon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Lon');
    for (inc = 0; inc < xlat.length; inc++) {
      var latcode = xlat[inc].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      var loncode = xlon[inc].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      var GeoBus = {lat: latcode, lng: loncode};
      new google.maps.Marker({position: GeoBus, map: map});
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat:48.3908449361675, lng:-4.48680591961381}
        });
}
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDw8GYeGNJySG_KDkhBFj4uHadD6G1Ahy4&callback=initMap">

</script>
```

But I obtain this issue:

```
Ligne1.html:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseXML' of undefined
    at initMap (Ligne1.html:48)
    at js?key=AIzaSyDw8GYeGNJySG_KDkhBFj4uHadD6G1Ahy4&callback=initMap:97
    at js?key=AIzaSyDw8GYeGNJySG_KDkhBFj4uHadD6G1Ahy4&callback=initMap:66
    at Object._.Vd (js?key=AIzaSyDw8GYeGNJySG_KDkhBFj4uHadD6G1Ahy4&callback=initMap:64)
    at fe (js?key=AIzaSyDw8GYeGNJySG_KDkhBFj4uHadD6G1Ahy4&callback=initMap:66)
    at js?key=AIzaSyDw8GYeGNJySG_KDkhBFj4uHadD6G1Ahy4&callback=initMap:147
    at Object.google.maps.Load (js?key=AIzaSyDw8GYeGNJySG_KDkhBFj4uHadD6G1Ahy4&callback=initMap:21)
    at js?key=AIzaSyDw8GYeGNJySG_KDkhBFj4uHadD6G1Ahy4&callback=initMap:146
    at js?key=AIzaSyDw8GYeGNJySG_KDkhBFj4uHadD6G1Ahy4&callback=initMap:147
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: see this `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&callback=initMap` ... it calls `initMap` without an argument ... you seem to be trying to do two things with one function that only expects to be called one way

Comment: Thanks we removed "&callback=initMap" but now i've this error: InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: `xlat[inc].childNodes[0].nodeValue` is probably not a number - `console.log(JSON.stringify(GeoBus))` after assigning to it ... does it look right?

Comment: Yes, it's a number, you can check it through this link : [XML](https://applications002.brest-metropole.fr/WIPOD01/Transport/REST/getGeolocatedVehiclesPosition?format=xml&route_id=1&trip_headsign=Fort%20Montbarey) or [JSON](https://applications002.brest-metropole.fr/WIPOD01/Transport/REST/getGeolocatedVehiclesPosition?format=json&route_id=1&trip_headsign=Fort%20Montbarey). I will try your console.log when i finish my day

Comment: no, it's a **string** - see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `xlat[inc].childNodes[0].nodeValue` is **not** a number, it's a string - so, make it a number - solved ... but, you initialise map AFTER you try to add markers - so that's an issue too

see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33L3zbwq/) for working version of your code (for some reason it won't run in a snippet here

```
function initMap(xml) {
    var xlat, xlon, inc, xmlDoc, GeoBus, marker;
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; //line 48
    xlat = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Lat');
    xlon = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Lon');
    // initialise the map first
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {
            lat: 48.3908449361675,
            lng: -4.48680591961381
        }
    });
    for (inc = 0; inc < xlat.length; inc++) {
        var latcode = xlat[inc].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var loncode = xlon[inc].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var GeoBus = {
            lat: +latcode, // +latcode - makes it a Number
            lng: +loncode // +loncode - ditto
        };
        console.log(GeoBus);
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: GeoBus,
            map: map
        });
    }
}
```